# can't delete empty rows from xlsx with vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, range, row, delete-row

I've got a vbscript that converts a specific range of rows to a csv file.
My problem is it also copies empty rows. How can I delete complete empty rows before copying or exclude them from copying?

My code:

```
Public Sub xlsToCsv()    
    Const WorkingDir = "C:\Test\"
    Const xlCSV = 24
    Const xlUp = -4162

    Dim fso, SaveName, myFile
    Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, wsSource, wsTarget

    myFile = "source_file.xlsx"
    SaveName = "test.csv"

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
        If Not .FileExists(WorkingDir & myFile) Then
            MsgBox "File not found:" & vbCrLf & WorkingDir & myFile, vbInformation, "Script Cancelled"
            WScript.Quit
        End If
    End With

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    objExcel.Visible = False
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(WorkingDir & myFile)
    Set wsSource = objWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set wsTarget = objWorkbook.Sheets.Add()

    With wsTarget
    .Cells(1,1).Value = "ID"
    .Cells(1,2).Value = "NAME"
    .Cells(1,3).Value = "DESC"
    End With

    wsSource.Activate
    wsSource.Range("A:F").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).‌​EntireRow.Delete

    With wsSource
    .Range("F7", .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy wsTarget.Range("A2")
    .Range("A7", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy wsTarget.Range("B2")
    .Range("E7", .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy wsTarget.Range("C2")
    End With

    objWorkbook.SaveAs WorkingDir & SaveName, xlCSV
    objWorkbook.Close True

    Set objWorkbook = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set myFolder = Nothing
End Sub

call xlsToCsv()
```

With this command "wsSource.Range("A:F").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).‌​EntireRow.Delete" ended with the error code 800A0408 - invalid chars.

Comment: Why the ***double dots*** in the last statement ??

Comment: to define the range? or is it not necessary to define a range?

Comment: @nolags Change it to `.Range`.

Comment: @GTAVLover changed it to ".Range" .. gives me invalid char error code: 800A0408 in the same line!

Comment: edited changes and error message above!